# Visibility of decal on three.js bottle is dependent on camera angle

Tags: reactjs, three.js, 3d, react-three-fiber

I created a 3D bottle with Blender that I intend to embed in a website via three.js. The bottle is supposed to rotate and I might end up using the OrbitControls, so it needs to look okay from all sides.

I'm familiar with the basics and most of it already works.

However I have trouble with the "label" on the bottle. There is a mesh cylinder "around" the bottle that holds the decal image.
The decal shows fine when the camera is looking at it from below.

e.g. with camera settings:

```
position: [0, -0.45, 8],
rotation: [0.07, 0, 0],
```

[image: decal visible]

However when the camera looks on it from above, the decal ends up "behind" the bottle.
e.g. with camera settings:

```
position: [0, 1, 8],
rotation: [-0.11, 0, 0],
```

[image: decal hidden]

It also observable when moving the camera up and down with the OrbitalControls.

I added a MWE on [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/qyts4c?file=%2Fpackage.json%3A19%2C24&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpug2mhd00062v6e1qzquuwr%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpug2mhc00022v6e6oml4ohk%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpug2mhc00032v6e0znrt775%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpug2mhc00052v6e5n1vkqcj%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B48.35988014508753%252C51.64011985491247%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clpug2mhc00022v6e6oml4ohk%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpug2mhc00022v6e6oml4ohk%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpuip8l700022v6e1xtfjjs8%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A99%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A8%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A99%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A8%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FBottle.jsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpuk3efq00022v6e3fwfvlmu%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A19%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A24%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A19%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A24%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fpackage.json%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpuk3efq00022v6e3fwfvlmu%2522%257D%252C%2522clpug2mhc00052v6e5n1vkqcj%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpug2mhc00052v6e5n1vkqcj%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpuje8vb00gr2v6ert6v97fc%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpuj7h1g004i2v6eg8l6fwzf%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpuje8vb00gr2v6ert6v97fc%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clpug2mhc00032v6e0znrt775%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpug2mhc00032v6e0znrt775%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpuj10r401012v6e7u1mzft0%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clpvbi502000xediacpt90mvy%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpuj10r401012v6e7u1mzft0%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

The decal mesh is far enough from the bottle so that z-fighting isn't the issue.
I already tried to increase the diameter of the decal mesh, and even with a real big diameter of the decal mesh, there is the same problem.

I think the problem might be the way three.js calculates which item (bottle <> mesh with decal) is closer to the camera, since both meshes have a similar center. But I cannot figure about how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set render order property to 1, looks fine now.

```
<mesh
          geometry={nodes.Print.geometry}
          position={nodes.Print.position}
          rotation={nodes.Print.rotation}
          scale={nodes.Print.scale}
          renderOrder={1}
        >
          <meshStandardMaterial
            shininess={800}
            transparent
            depthWrite={false}
            map={printDecal}
            side={THREE.FrontSide}
          />
        </mesh>
```